# Android: Running different test on different Emulators/real devices attached to same machine

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-testing

I have three different test applications which are installed in three different emulators and I need to initiate those test at the same time. But am not sure how would I do this. Requirement is to run these test from same machine in different devices/emulators.

I am trying to write a script having the `adb` commands for running tests but am not sure how would I decide which test to run on which device. Here are the commands :

```
./adb shell am instrument -w com.pb.demo.test1/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
./adb shell am instrument -w com.org.demo.test2/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
./adb shell am instrument -w com.demo.ec.test3/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

And I have scheduled this script to run at a particular time. So when this script would trigger, three different test cases should be initiated on three different devices `attached to same machine(for e.g. my local)`.

How can I achieve this? How would I change my commands such that they know which emulator to run test on? Is it really feasible? Please guide.

PS: I am using [genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) for multiple emulators. These are
`192.168.56.101:5555 device
192.168.56.102:5555 device`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "-s Device" option when calling adb:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#directingcommands

Comment: so in above scenario, since port is same (5555), how am I going to direct my commands?

Comment: the port is the same, but not the IP address. "adb -s 192.168.56.101:5555 shell and adb -s 192.168.56.102:5555 shell" work and should connect to different devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use following way to launch your emulator

```
CD C:/Users/XXX/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/tools
emulator -avd Device-2 -port 5561
```

In above command Device-2 will launch on port 5561 and note that port no should be more than 5554